# Find a key value based on a match in Javascript

Tags: javascript, list, dictionary, google-apps-script, nested-lists

I'm trying to return the uuid where the urns key has this match.

"urns": [
"whatsapp:27820111111"
],

What should be returned d7b9f88c-b359-4d69-926d-536c0d2892e0 since it has that phone number match. How can this be done programmatically.

Here's are the two dicts.

```
{
"next": "https://random.com=",
"previous": null,
"results": [ 
{
        "uuid": "g2ws8dh5-b359-4d69-926d-536c0d2892e0",
        "name": "James",
        "language": "eng",
        "urns": [
            "whatsapp:27333333333"
        ],
        "groups": [
            {
                "uuid": "57fs8430-3c78-42b7-876c-c385e36c1dba",
                "name": "Postbirth WhatsApp"
            }
        ],
        "fields": {
            "whatsapp_consent": null,
            "webhook_failure_count": null,
        },
        "blocked": false,
        "stopped": false,
        "created_on": "2020-12-01T07:50:58.736502Z",
        "modified_on": "2020-12-01T08:36:34.980359Z"
    },
{
        "uuid": "d7b9f88c-b359-4d69-926d-536c0d2892e0",
        "name": "Jane",
        "language": "eng",
        "urns": [
            "whatsapp:27820111111"
        ],
        "groups": [
            {
                "uuid": "e35f2e39-3c78-42b7-876c-c385e36c1dba",
                "name": "Prebirth WhatsApp"
            }
        ],
        "fields": {
            "whatsapp_consent": null,
            "webhook_failure_count": null,
        },
        "blocked": false,
        "stopped": false,
        "created_on": "2020-12-01T07:50:58.736502Z",
        "modified_on": "2020-12-01T08:36:34.980359Z"
    }
]
```

}

I'm able to loop through and find the urn but I'm not sure how to step back to get the uuid.

Answer (score 0):

Pass in the results array and the urn string to this function. If found it will return the uuid, else it will return null.

```
function getIdFromUrn(results, urn) {
    for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        const result = results[i];

        if (result.urns.includes(urn)) {
            return result.uuid; // urn found
        }
    }

    return null; // not found
}

console.log(getIdFromUrn(results, 'whatsapp:27820111111'));
```

Comment: I tested it. Works fine for me. Can you show how you passed the results array to the function? Maybe you passed the entire dictionary.

Comment: Oh yes, I passed in the entire dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to loop when you can use `find(...)` to match against a value.

**See demo below**

```js
var data = [{
    "uuid": "g2ws8dh5-b359-4d69-926d-536c0d2892e0",
    "name": "James",
    "language": "eng",
    "urns": [
      "whatsapp:27333333333"
    ],
    "groups": [{
      "uuid": "57fs8430-3c78-42b7-876c-c385e36c1dba",
      "name": "Postbirth WhatsApp"
    }],
    "fields": {
      "whatsapp_consent": null,
      "webhook_failure_count": null,
    },
    "blocked": false,
    "stopped": false,
    "created_on": "2020-12-01T07:50:58.736502Z",
    "modified_on": "2020-12-01T08:36:34.980359Z"
  },
  {
    "uuid": "d7b9f88c-b359-4d69-926d-536c0d2892e0",
    "name": "Jane",
    "language": "eng",
    "urns": [
      "whatsapp:27820111111"
    ],
    "groups": [{
      "uuid": "e35f2e39-3c78-42b7-876c-c385e36c1dba",
      "name": "Prebirth WhatsApp"
    }],
    "fields": {
      "whatsapp_consent": null,
      "webhook_failure_count": null,
    },
    "blocked": false,
    "stopped": false,
    "created_on": "2020-12-01T07:50:58.736502Z",
    "modified_on": "2020-12-01T08:36:34.980359Z"
  }
];

const lookingFor = "whatsapp:27820111111";

const foundIt = data.find(el => {
  return (el.urns.indexOf(lookingFor) !== -1);
});

console.log(foundIt.uuid);
```